# How do you programmatically create a System DSN using Powershell or .NET?

Tags: .net, powershell, dsn

How do you create a System DSN in the control panel on ones PC using Powershell or .NET?

Comment: ... using the database connection object's constructor?

Comment: I would use connection strings passed into the connection object.  Look at the things like SqlConnectionStringBuilder ...

Comment: What I meant was: How do you create a System DSN in the control panel on one's PC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with some registry edit. Refer this link:

http://derek858.blogspot.com/2010/02/create-32-bit-system-dsn-with.html

Note that for 64-bit you will be using `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Odbc\Odbc.ini\`